# Return dataframe with only last observations of e.g. patients, using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a dataframe where there are multiple rows per person and these correspond to different exam dates. I would now like to write a function using Rcpp so that I get a dataframe containing only the last observations. I currently have a code in R (adjusted from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/firstlast.htm), but since the dataframe has over 20 000 rows and 200 variables, this goes way too slow.

```
# function
 last.obs <- function(id,data){
   args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
   tmp <- data
   tmp$id <- eval(args$id,data)
   uni.id <- unique(tmp$id)

   last <- c()

   for (i in unique(uni.id)){
    temp<-tmp[which(tmp$id==i),]
    if (dim(temp)[1] > 1){
     last.temp<-temp[dim(temp)[1],]
    }else{last.temp<-temp}
    last<-rbind(last, last.temp)
   }
   last
  }

# create sample data
data <- data.frame("id"=sort(sample(letters[1:3],20,T)),"x1"=rnorm(20),
"x2"=rnorm(20), "x3"=sample(c("Drug","Treatment"),20,T))

# example of function
last.obs(id,data)
```

I have tried to write this in C++, but I do not know enough to write the whole function. I'm having troubles with subsetting the data, witholding only the last rows and finding the C++ equivalent of `rbind`. I would really like to get better in C++, so I would really be thankful if someone could help me with this. This is the code that I have until now (sorry for the crappy code).

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export("lastobs")]]
Rcpp::DataFrame lastobs(Rcpp::CharacterVector id, Rcpp::DataFrame data){
int unid = id.size();
Rcpp::CharacterVector id_data = data["id"];
Rcpp::CharacterVector id_loop;
Rcpp::NumericVector matchid;
Rcpp::DataFrame lastobs;

for(int i=0; i<unid;i++){
 id_loop = id(i);
 matchid = Rcpp::match(id_data,id_loop); 
// I do not know I can best proceed from here
}
return lastobs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> df = data.frame(A = c(1,2,2,3,3,3), B = c('a','a','b','a','b','c'))

  A B
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 2 b
4 3 a
5 3 b
6 3 c
```

For first observation:

```
> df[!duplicated(df$A), ]
  A B
1 1 a
2 2 a
4 3 a
```

For last observation:

```
> df[rev(!duplicated(rev(df$A))), ]

  A B
1 1 a
3 2 b
6 3 c
```

Comment: 0.05 seconds, I guess this is even better than writing it in C++. Thanks! Do you know why this is so much faster? I know that for loops are slow in R, so I already knew this was part of the problem, but I didn't expect that this code would be this fast.

Comment: I'm not sure what goes on under the hood... but reading the help doc i just found this: duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE) is equivalent to but faster than rev(duplicated(rev(x))). So maybe you can get it down to 0.04 seconds lol

Comment: You're right, using `df[!duplicated(df$A, fromLast = TRUE), ]` goes even faster. 0.03 seconds for a dataframe with 24665 rows and 275 variables, this is just crazy.